# How to do SSH on multiple server (listed in file ) and execute the multiple commnds (listed in file) through python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

hostname.txt

```
server1
server2
server3
server4
server5
```

command.txt

```
service httpd status
service dhcpd status
```

or some linux command need to push on every server.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I used paramiko but its wont be helpful.

Comment: https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/